# How can I get an array first key name in Twig?

Tags: php, twig, codeigniter-3

I want to get key name in array.

First, My admin controller wrote like this.

```
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    const FLASHDATA_NAME = "admin_notice";

    public function index()
    {
        $data['flash_message'] = $this->session->flashdata(self::FLASHDATA_NAME);
        $this->twig->display('index', $data);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata(self::FLASHDATA_NAME, array('success' => 'create complete'));
        redirect('index');
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata(self::FLASHDATA_NAME, array('danger' => 'delete complete'));
        redirect('index');
    }
}
```

If method has been done, My flashdata contain message like this.

```
'flash_message' => array(
    'success' => 'create complete'
);
```

So I wrote my view like this.

```
{% if flash_message %}
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
  <button type="button" class="close" title="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
  <h5><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>{{ flash_message | first }}</h5>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I wish i could use php key function to change css classname "success" or "danger".

```
{% if flash_message %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ key(flash_message[0]) }} alert-dismissible">
  <button type="button" class="close" title="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
  <h5><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>{{ flash_message | first }}</h5>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I know keys function but that need to loop an array. I do not want to do because an array has only one element.
That is why I ask. How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this.
I could get key name by this code.

```
{{ flash_message | keys | first }}
```